# Backdrop-filter blur not working on submenu

Tags: css, wordpress, blur, gaussianblur, uiblureffect

I'm trying to applicate the `backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);` in a submenu, but it's not working at all.

This is my setup (WordPress site):

The main menu is a sticky menu, with a the color property `.style-color-550572-bg` tweaked with this configuration:

`.style-color-550572-bg{ background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); -webkit-backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px); backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px); }`

So the main menu is showing blur correctly. The problem occurs in the submenu, I have this same color but it doesn't apply any configuration, so when I use the Inspect in Google Chrome, I see it has a property assigned to it `.submenu-light .menu-horizontal .menu-smart ul` with a background color. I've manually override the CSS for this property with this configuration:

`.submenu-light .menu-horizontal .menu-smart ul{ background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); -webkit-backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px); backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px); }`

What I'm getting is just a white background with a 0.8 of transparency, but no blur at all.

I've tried everything here, from `!important` to `:before`, but nothing seems to be working.

I'm expecting the sub-menu have an 80% of transparency and have a blur background.

This is the whole header code, just in case it helps:

```html
<div class="row-menu limit-width">
<div class="row-menu-inner">
    <div id="logo-container-mobile" class="col-lg-0 logo-container middle">
      <div id="main-logo" class="navbar-header style-light">
        <a href="https://conservationdiver.com/" class="navbar-brand" data-padding-shrink="0" data-minheight="20"><div class="logo-image main-logo logo-skinnable" data-maxheight="45" style="height: 45px;"><img decoding="async" src="https://conservationdiver.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/CD_horizontal_grey-text_white-diver.png" alt="logo" width="4000" height="2000" class="img-responsive"></div></a>
      </div>
      <div class="mmb-container"><div class="mobile-additional-icons"></div><div class="mobile-menu-button mobile-menu-button-light lines-button"><span class="lines"><span></span></span></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 main-menu-container middle">
      <div class="menu-horizontal menu-dd-shadow-std ">
        <div class="menu-horizontal-inner">
          <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-main navbar-nav-first"><ul id="menu-home" class="menu-primary-inner menu-smart sm" data-smartmenus-id="16923856045035933"><li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15 menu-item-link" style="-webkit-transition-delay:0.1s; -moz-transition-delay:0.1s; -ms-transition-delay:0.1s; -o-transition-delay:0.1s; transition-delay:0.1s"><a title="Who we are" href="#">Who we are<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li class="mega-menu menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children" style="-webkit-transition-delay:0.15000000000000002s; -moz-transition-delay:0.15000000000000002s; -ms-transition-delay:0.15000000000000002s; -o-transition-delay:0.15000000000000002s; transition-delay:0.15000000000000002s"><a href="#" class="highlighted">Our Courses<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-dropdown"></i></a>
<ul role="menu" class="mega-menu-inner in-mega mega-menu-three open-animated" style="visibility: visible; pointer-events: auto; width: 1068px; top: 100%; left: -126px; right: auto; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 1px; z-index: 2;">
<li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-21 dropdown"><a title="RESEARCH &amp; MONITORING" href="#" data-type="title">RESEARCH &amp; MONITORING<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-dropdown"></i></a>
<ul role="menu" class="drop-menu">
<li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-22"><a title="Ecological Monitoring Program" href="#"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-arrow-right2"></i>Ecological Monitoring Program<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-23"><a title="Coral Reef Ecology" href="#"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-arrow-right2"></i>Coral Reef Ecology<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24"><a title="Coral Taxonomy &amp; ID" href="#"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-arrow-right2"></i>Coral Taxonomy &amp; ID<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-25"><a title="Coral Disease Monitoring and ID" href="#"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-arrow-right2"></i>Coral Disease Monitoring and ID<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-233" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-233"><a title="Advanced Ecological Monitoring Program" href="https://conservationdiver.com/conservation-courses/advanced-ecological-monitoring-program/"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-arrow-right2"></i>Advanced Ecological Monitoring Program<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-27"><a title="Competition and Biofouling" href="#">Competition and Biofouling<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-28"><a title="Water Quality Testing" href="#">Water Quality Testing<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-29"><a title="Sea Turtle Ecology &amp; Monitoring" href="#">Sea Turtle Ecology &amp; Monitoring<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-30"><a title="Shark Ecology and Population Studies" href="#">Shark Ecology and Population Studies<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-31"><a title="Seahorse Ecology &amp; Monitoring" href="#">Seahorse Ecology &amp; Monitoring<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-32"><a title="EMP Marine Plants: Seagrass" href="#">EMP Marine Plants: Seagrass<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-33"><a title="EMP Marine Plants: Macroalgae" href="#">EMP Marine Plants: Macroalgae<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-34"><a title="Nudibranch Ecology &amp; ID" href="#">Nudibranch Ecology &amp; ID<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-35"><a title="Giant Clam Nurseries and Population Studies" href="#">Giant Clam Nurseries and Population Studies<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-36"><a title="Coral Taxonomist" href="#">Coral Taxonomist<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-37"><a title="Whale Conservationist" href="#">Whale Conservationist<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-38"><a title="Whale Research Assistant" href="#">Whale Research Assistant<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-39" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-39 dropdown"><a title="PROTECTION" href="#" data-type="title">PROTECTION<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-dropdown"></i></a>
<ul role="menu" class="drop-menu">
<li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-40"><a title="Mooring Line Maintenance &amp; Installation" href="#"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-arrow-right2"></i>Mooring Line Maintenance &amp; Installation<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-41"><a title="Coral Predators: Population Management &amp; Monitoring" href="#"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-arrow-right2"></i>Coral Predators: Population Management &amp; Monitoring<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-42"><a title="Sea Turtle Hatcheries &amp; Head-starting" href="#"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-arrow-right2"></i>Sea Turtle Hatcheries &amp; Head-starting<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-43"><a title="Plastic Pollution Monitoring &amp; Assessment" href="#"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-arrow-right2"></i>Plastic Pollution Monitoring &amp; Assessment<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-44 dropdown"><a title="RESTORATION" href="#" data-type="title">RESTORATION<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-dropdown"></i></a>
<ul role="menu" class="drop-menu">
<li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-45"><a href="#" title="Coral Restoration Theory and Techniques">Coral Restoration Theory and Techniques<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46"><a title="Artificial Reef Theory and Techniques" href="#">Artificial Reef Theory and Techniques<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-47"><a href="#" title="Coral Spawning and Larval Culturing">Coral Spawning and Larval Culturing<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-48"><a title="Mineral Accretion Device Basics and Techniques" href="#">Mineral Accretion Device Basics and Techniques<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-49"><a title="Mangrove Restoration" href="#">Mangrove Restoration<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17 menu-item-link" style="-webkit-transition-delay:0.2s; -moz-transition-delay:0.2s; -ms-transition-delay:0.2s; -o-transition-delay:0.2s; transition-delay:0.2s"><a href="#" title="Training Centers">Training Centers<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-18 menu-item-link" style="-webkit-transition-delay:0.25s; -moz-transition-delay:0.25s; -ms-transition-delay:0.25s; -o-transition-delay:0.25s; transition-delay:0.25s"><a href="#" title="News">News<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-19 menu-item-link" style="-webkit-transition-delay:0.30000000000000004s; -moz-transition-delay:0.30000000000000004s; -ms-transition-delay:0.30000000000000004s; -o-transition-delay:0.30000000000000004s; transition-delay:0.30000000000000004s"><a href="#" title="Publications">Publications<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-20 menu-item-link" style="-webkit-transition-delay:0.35s; -moz-transition-delay:0.35s; -ms-transition-delay:0.35s; -o-transition-delay:0.35s; transition-delay:0.35s"><a href="#" title="Foundation">Foundation<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-dropdown"></i></a></li>
</ul></div><div class="uncode-close-offcanvas-mobile lines-button close navbar-mobile-el"><span class="lines"></span></div><div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-last navbar-extra-icons"><ul class="menu-smart sm menu-icons" data-smartmenus-id="16923856045057957"><li class="menu-item-link search-icon style-light dropdown " style="-webkit-transition-delay:0.4s; -moz-transition-delay:0.4s; -ms-transition-delay:0.4s; -o-transition-delay:0.4s; transition-delay:0.4s"><a href="#" class="trigger-overlay search-icon" data-area="search" data-container="box-container">
<i class="fa fa-search3"></i><span class="desktop-hidden"><span>Search</span></span><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-dropdown desktop-hidden"></i>
</a><ul role="menu" class="drop-menu desktop-hidden">
<li>
<form class="search" method="get" action="https://conservationdiver.com/">
  <input type="search" class="search-field no-livesearch" placeholder="Search…" value="" name="s" title="Search…"></form>
</li>
</ul></li></ul></div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question with a Stack Snippet `<>` with your HTML and CSS - the inline CSS doesn't really help us. You can also strip down your HTML to the most basic elements (we don't need all of the WP code or classes).